# Xpath,php and jquery validation script

Tags: php, jquery

I'm create a deal agregator but first i need to put xpath into database but before that I need to type xpath and website into my fields to see what result I will get... so some type of xpath validation tool:

Here is my code for type xpath adresses into textfields:

xpathadd.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>
<script>
addToDatabase = function() {
    alert("addToDatabase called");
    $.post("generatingxpath.php", {
        websource: $('#websource').val(),
        links: $('#links').val(),
        title: $('#title').val(),
        image: $('#image').val(),
        discount: $('#discount').val(),
        price: $('#price').val(),
        description: $('#description').val(),
        coordinates: $('#coordinates').val()
    }, function(data) {
        $("#result").html(data);
    });
};​
</script>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="generatingxpath.php">

  <p>
    <label for="websource"></label>
    Web source:
    <input name="websource" type="text" id="websource" size="70">
  is:</p>
  <p>

    <label for="links"></label>
    Links:
    <input name="links" type="text" id="links" size="77">
    OK!
  </p>
  <p>

    <label for="title"></label>
    Title:
    <input name="title" type="text" id="title" size="78">
  is:</p>
  <p>

    <label for="image"></label>
    Image:
    <input name="image" type="text" id="image" size="76">
  show:</p>
  <p>

    <label for="discount"></label>
    Disscount:
    <input name="discount" type="text" id="discount" size="72">
  is:</p>
  <p>

    <label for="price"></label>
    Price:
    <input name="price" type="text" id="price" size="77">
  is:</p>
  <p>

    <label for="description"></label>
    Desription:
    <input name="description" type="text" id="description" size="72">
  is:</p>
  <p>

    <label for="coordinates"></label>
    Coordinates:
    <input name="coordinates" type="text" id="coordinates" size="70">
  lat,lng is:</p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Preview">
or
<input type="submit" name="Add to database" id="Add to database" value="Add To Database">
<a href="javascript:addToDatabase();">Add to database</a>
  </p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</form>
    <div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>​
```

and generatingxpath.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>

<head>

<title>GENERATING XPATH</title>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

</head>



<body>

<?php


function curl($url){

        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip");

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        $data = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);

        return $data;

}



libxml_use_internal_errors(true);


$websource = $_POST["websource"];
$links = $_POST["links"];
$title = $_POST["title"];
$image = $_POST["image"];
$disscount = $_POST["disscount"];
$price = $_POST["price"];
$description = $_POST["description"];
$coordinates = $_POST["coordinates"];


//start generating xpath script

$dom = new DOMDocument(); 

@$dom->loadHTMLFile($websource); 

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom); 

$entries = $xpath->query($links);

$output = array(); 

$i = 1;

foreach($entries as $e) {   

  $dom2 = new DOMDocument(); 

  @$dom2->loadHTMLFile($websource . $e->textContent); 

  $xpath2 = new DOMXPath($dom2); 

  $data = array();

  $data['websource']= ($websource . $e->textContent);

  $data['title'] = trim($xpath2->query($title)->item(0)->textContent); 

  $data['description'] = trim($xpath2->query($description)->item(0)->textContent); 

  $data['image'] = trim($xpath2->query($image)->item(0)->textContent); 

  $string = $xpath2->query($coordintes)->item(1)->textContent; 

  preg_match_all('#(([0-9-]+){1,3}.([0-9]+))#is', $string, $matches); 

  $data['lat']=$matches[1];
  $data['lng']=$matches[2];
  $data['disscount'] = trim($xpath2->query($disscount)->item(0)->textContent);
    $data['price'] = trim($xpath2->query($price)->item(0)->textContent);


//print to see that all is fine or need to change some xpath direction

  echo $data['websource'];
  echo $data['links'];
  echo $data['title'];
  echo $data['image'];
  echo $data['disscount'];
  echo $data['price'];
  echo $data['lat'];
  echo $data['lng'];
  echo $data['description'];


    $output[] = $data; 



} 



?>

</body>

</html>
```

but I get only Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/pluspon/public_html/test/generatingxpath.php on line 67
??? WHY? where is problem?

Comment: http://test.pluspon.com/xpathadd.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of `$_POST["links"]` does not match in the DOM/XML!

Comment: $_POST["links"] exist into doom